# Not able to access files in resource folder

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have created a new module in Intellij with directory structure as follows:
 *new-module -> src -> main -> java -> config -> resources -> ConfigResources.java*
 *new-module -> src -> main-> resources -> config -> resources -> config.properties*

When I build my intellij project, I see that the resource file is being copied correctly to "out/production/resources" directory

Now when I try to access this file through following code, it returns null:
    `ConfigResources.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties")`

From what I have read from several other posts,  the above code tries to load file from same path in resource folder, but it didn't work for me.

What else have I tried:

1. `ClassLoader.class.getResource()`
2. Copied the properties file to java directory itself, but after build classes folder contains the classes and the properties file is copied to resource folder
3. I tried giving the relative path from resource folder but it didn't work either
4. Manually copied the file to classes folder then it works(obviously!)

How can I access the resource file? (It's a gradle project and uses java 11)
Do I need to set any configuration in intellij or need to include something in my build.gradle file?

Comment: Not quite sure if it helps, but did you mark your resources folder as an source folder in your project? The "config.properties" file must be on your classpath. Otherwise the method won't find it

Comment: @the hand of NOD - I have marked the "resources" directory as resource path in intellij. How do I check the classpath?

Comment: For example: ```public static void main (String args[]) {
        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
        for(URL url: urls){
         System.out.println(url.getFile());
        }
   } ```

Comment: the above code doesn't work in Java 11. -> java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Try to add an additional folder "foo" to the resources directory. Sounds a bit confusing, but it works.

*new-module -> src -> main -> resources -> config -> resources -> foo -> config.properties*

`ConfigResources.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(foo/config.properties);`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<>();
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream(collectionName+".json");

try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is)) {
    // Read JSON file
    Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
    JSONArray documentArray = (JSONArray) obj;
    // Iterate over documentArray
    documentArray.forEach(doc -> {
        Document document = Document.parse(doc.toString());
        docs.add(document);
    });
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return docs;
```

I'm also face the same issue but i fixed like this to get data from the resource

Comment: i used to get json file from the resource folder but its works for me bro